# KDMF Driver Deployment to Windows 7 Virtual Machine

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, driver

I get the following error when I try to deploy the KDMF Driver template to a provisioned Windows 7 host:

error: Network debugging is not available for Windows versions 6.1 or earlier.

I've tried updating the host by installing the latest WDK and the Windows SDK. I'm at a loss for what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target computer must be windows 8 or later for kernel mode debugging over a network.

Comment: I suspected this, but I can't seem to find a specific table or paragraph stating that kernel mode debugging over a network is only available on Windows 8 platforms.

Is there any other way to debug a kernel mode driver on a Windows 7 virtual machine?

Comment: @user2416758 Max Ouellet made a good suggestion below for debugging on Windows 7 VM.

Answer (score 2):

For a Windows 7 VM, you will need to do kernel debugging through serial. If you are using HyperV, you can simply configure a virtual COM port that goes through a named pipe.

In Visual Studio, you can then configure your kernel debugger settings for serial debugging over a named pipe. Even outside of Visual Studio, that's the most reliable way I know to kernel debug a Win7 VM.